# NetworkManager not listing wifi

Tags: linux, gnome, networkmanager

A few days ago my computer(Arch Linux + Gnome) suddenly couldn't connect to the network, NetworkManager couldn't scan any wifi connection. `systemctl status wpa_supplicant` output `ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Operation not supported`.I tried to downgrade NetworkManger, wpa_supplicant, kernel and so on, but nothing work. And then I tried to use another application -- wifi-menu to connect wifi. But the same issue encounted.

I realized it might not be the cause of applications but the driver issue.

Output of `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`

```
[    4.676519] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.676520] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    4.676987] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.952d9faa.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.919999] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    4.928746] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.929049] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    4.981351] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: d4:6d:6d:fb:e7:4e
[    5.061679] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.418234] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.550877] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.617586] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

No suspicious failures founded. And then I tried to reload the module `iwlmvm`. Surprisingly it works! NetworkManger start working fine.

But why?

The output of `lshw -c network`

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 78
       serial: b2:c2:56:48:d6:1e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.11-arch1-1 firmware=36.952d9faa.0 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:147 memory:b4100000-b4101fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: br0
       serial: d6:f5:c0:1f:55:1d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes
```

Comment: Run `lshw` in a terminal and see if the Wifi chip is marked "UNCLAIMED", which would indicate yoru driver (if it's still there) doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @xenoid After rebooting my computer, NetworkManager couldn't still list wifi.   The output of `lshw -c network` seems to be good, and it is no different from when NetworkManager works normally.